# Spring AMQP DirectContainer keeps requeuing on errors

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

using Spring Boot 2.1.6 and Spring AMQP/RabbitMQ neither of these application.properties do trigger a DLX/DLQ when an Exception is thrown in the @RabbitListener:

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.default-requeue-rejected=false
spring.rabbitmq.listener.default-requeue-rejected=false
```

instead [isDefaultRequeueRejected()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/DirectMessageListenerContainer.java#L1140) always evaluates to true. how do I change that to false to cause a proper DLX/DLQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.type=direct
```

?

I get the same result as you when that is missing - none of the listener properties are applied, including the one you are talking about.

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.type=direct
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.default-requeue-rejected=false
```

works fine for me; failed messages are rejected without being requeued.

The default container type is `simple` so the `direct` property you set is ignored.

Comment: sorry, we are explicitly using the direct-container
`@Bean DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; edit the question to show your configuration. If you are creating your own factory for some reason, you should use boot's factory configurer to apply the properties.

Comment: doh, that hit the nail on the head, we are missing the DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer to inject exactly those properties - thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the difference between simple and direct?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers - it doesn't help people find answers to questions and it's hard to quote text from a link when answering. Always ask a new question. See [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#choose-container).